# Can a TV Network refuse to air political Ads they do not agree with?

Tags: donald-trump, advertising, fcc, fec

Can a TV Broadcaster legally refuse to air Political Ads under FCC rules & precedent governing political advertising if a registered **political candidate** or **PAC** were to air perceived negative **political ads** that do not align with it's editorial political leanings?

Example:
Fox News (initially did) refused to air Tom Steyer's needtoimpeach.com Ads citing "Negative viewer reaction"

> "Due to the strong negative reaction to their ad by our viewers, we could not in good conscience take their money"
>   [Washington Post Article](https://washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2017/11/06/fox-news-stops-running-tv-ad-calling-for-trump-impeachment/)

The question specifically asks about Political Advertising by or in support of an Election Candidate. Unlike the Tom Steyer Ads that may or may  not be considered **Election Ads** therefore may not be bound by Election Ad rules. This is a purely *neutral* question about the law, not loaded or biased to any side since this can affect any candidate or network regardless of party affiliation or partisan bias.